# Override "Paste As" dialog

Tags: enterprise-architect

When I drag Class element onto my diagram there is a window fired "Paste Class1", where I can choose the drop type, such as "Link","Property","Instance (Object)" and so.
I need to change that behavior - when I drag from ProjectBrowser I need apply only drop type "Link" and hide any variants from end user. Is it possible to do that via addin or anything else ?
Sparx 13.5

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can write an addin that reacts on the right mouse but (IIRC) not on a drag operation. Write a feature request and forget it. Maybe Geert has another idea.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't change the behavior of that dialog.

What you *can* do in an add-in is overrule whatever the user chose after the fact, and make it into a link anyway. (e.g. deleting the instance from the model and set the elementID of the classifier in the `DiagramObject` instead)

There is also a checkbox option to only show this window when Ctrl-drag is used. That might help to avoid mishaps as well.

[image]